# Hi "Mr." Brad Pitt! in column

Tags: excel

Column A - first name list

Column B - last name list

Column C - salutation list

I want in column D: HI "salutation" + first name + last name!

I try ="Hi &C1&" "&A1&" "&B1&"!" -> result Hi Mr. Brad Pitt!

But I want the result Hi "Mr." Brad Pitt!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two double quotes where you want each double quote to be, in order to escape it.

`="Hi """&C1&""" "&A1&" "&B1&"!"`

Answer (score 2):

you can use 2 double quotes to get a double quote in your text.

Try this instead: `="Hi """&C1&""" "&A1&" "&B1&"!"`

Answer (score 1):

Try below formula-

```
="Hi " & CHAR(34) & C1 & CHAR(34) & " " & A1 &" "&B1&"!"
```